# Get the name of a decorated function as string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a decorator structure that follows the syntax below.

```
def decorator(arg1=[], arg2=[]):
    def inner(func):
        # do some stuff using arg1, arg2, and func
        pass
    return inner
```

This allows me to decorate functions as

```
@decorator(arg1=["a", "b"])
def foo():
    pass
    # stuff
```

In one case I end up passing the `foo` as an argument to some other function where I get its name as a string with `foo.__name__`. Unfortunately, once I added the decorator the `__name__` property on `foo` no longer exists. Is there some way for me to get it still get this?

Comment: Please, add [mre]. i.e. instead of explain that "one case", show the code

Comment: Um... `foo` is `None`, not a function anymore. Fix that first.

Comment: Your `pass` has to be short for a third function definition that `inner` returns... right? (If not, that's part of your problem. *Maybe* you modify `func` in place and return `func`, but you can't simply pass or return `None`.)

Comment: @chepner If that were the case, `foo.__name__` would exist. They said it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

This is what `functools.wraps` is for.

```
from functools import wraps


def decorator(arg1=None, arg2=None): # Don't use mutable default values
    if arg1 is None:
        arg1 = []
    if arg2 is None:
        arg2 = []

    def inner(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def _(...):
            ...
        return _
    return inner
```

`wraps` takes various bits of information about its argument, and returns a decorator that applies that information to the function being decorated. In particular, it applies `_.__name__ = func.__name__`.